# Filtering country names by length

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I’m trying to write code that would allow me to take country names out of an array whose names don’t meet the minimum and maximum length requirements. So let’s say on my page I type in 4 for the minimum and 6 for the maximum. I want my page to only show country names with 4 to 6 letters in their names. In Java, I would have written this

```
String[] newArr = new String[0];
int pos = 0;

for(int i = 0; i > min && i<max; i++) {
    newArr[pos++] = oldArr[i]
}
```

But I’m not sure what I’d write in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` on the `countryNames` array. Loop over each element and check the length with `minLength` value as `4` and `maxLength` value as `6`.

```js
var minLength = 4; maxLength = 6;
var countryNames = ['abc', 'India', 'China', 'America', 'pqr', 'Bhutan'];
var res = countryNames.filter(function(country){
  if(country.length > minLength && country.length < maxLength){
    return country;
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

**USING forEach**

```js
var minLength = 4; maxLength = 6;
var countryNames = ['abc', 'India', 'China', 'America', 'pqr', 'Bhutan'];
var res = [];
countryNames.forEach(function(country){
  if(country.length > minLength && country.length < maxLength){
    res.push(country);
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array's `.filter()` method to filter out names like this:

```js
let array = ['Pakistan', 'India', 'China', 'Iran', 'USA',
             'United Kingdom', 'Iraq', 'Ghana'];
let min = 4,
    max = 6;
    
let result = array.filter(({ length }) => (length >= min && length <= max));

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)